# Can you fully remove a user's (administrator's) password in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security, passwords

I've recently sent my computer to be repaired and I am almost certain that I set a password to my account - the only account on the system.

After the repair has been completed I've found out that my account had no password set.

So please tell me - did I forget to set it, or are there some tools to remove user's password?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: W7 Password change using a System Repair disc or a W7 install disc...http://superuser.com/a/395392/40928

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are tools to remove the user's password. Most repair shops use them when you haven't given them your password, it's much quicker than calling you for the password.

Also see http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/01/kon-boot-getting-into-a-clients-computer-without-using-a-portal-gun/

Comment: but .. is it even LEGAL ?!

Comment: Well, technically not without permission... But if you gave them your computer to fix, they probably needed to do so.

Comment: And can I check, weather the passwords **was** set or not?

Comment: @elmes probably not, removal by means of such tools isn't logged. You could always try asking the repair people/shop/guy if they removed it...

Comment: You'd need to be able to check the time stamp on an individual key in the registry. I'm not sure if that's possible. But like BloodPhilia said, if you sent your computer off for repair and did not give them your password, it is usually actually MORE secure that they wipe your password. If they know your computer password it is highly likely they know the password to your banking sites, your email, and many other things. If they simply wipe the password, they never had to see your initial password. When I did support I tended to wipe passwords and tell people to set it up again rather than ask.

Comment: Important side note that the process of wiping the password will invalidate the certificate for the user account so if you used windows to encrypt files you will not be able to recover the files if you did not have a [backup of the certificate](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Back-up-Encrypting-File-System-EFS-certificate) before the wipe.

Comment: And what about passwords in MS Outlook? They are gone too!

Comment: @elmes Yes that's because those are in the same store. All passwords saved with the password store API will be gone.